# CSS Height auto with overflow scroll and a max-height

Tags: css

I have in the moment this window

[image: What i already have]

Those 3 parents div are using float to stay side by side each other and with max-height equal to the window height, so those 3 divs are responsive, the 3 div is a chat and inside it i have 3 more div, a title, chat and options. I want the height of the chat to always fill all div without taking the remaining divs out, I already tried with height: 80%; but of course this doesnt work because this is relative to the parent and option comes out, but using height: 80vh; also doenst work and i dont know why.
When i decrease the height window this happens:

[image: Problem]

How can i resolve this problem to always I decrease window and the chat automatically adjusting without happening what shows in the previous image.

Code of 3 div:

-HTML:

```
<div id="talk-CQ-SP">
    <div class="chat_talkCQ_SP no-transition">

        <h4 class="chat-pv-name"></h4>
        <div class="messages">

        </div>
        <div class="send-inputs container-fluid mt-2">
            <div class="mx-auto d-flex">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm send-message" name="send-message" style="height:auto;">


            </div>
        </div><div class="rni-input container-fluid row justify-content-center mt-2">
            <label for="send-rni" class="form-text mr-2">RNI</label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-CSS:

```
#talk-CQ-SP {
    width: 38%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

#talk-CQ-SP .chat_talkCQ_SP {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #fff;
    top: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#talk-CQ-SP .messages {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: insert your html and css pls

Comment: give it a try with display:flex and it should work out much easier, float is not meant for that kind of layout.

Comment: i tried flex too, but not works too

Comment: The IDs in your CSS don't match your HTML

Comment: here is an example with flex : https://jsfiddle.net/0Lqgt7vk/1/ , also to avoid messages's heights to stretch the whole row, that col  needs to be removed from the flow via position

Comment: Thanks  G-Cyrillus, that's right, I had so much time and it seems to be easy, I'll try